# Excel VBA to look for the last non-blank cell in a column and convert it to a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column thats rows are currently filled with this formula: 
    =IF(VLOOKUP(H3,B:D,3,0)="NOT_FOUND","",VLOOKUP(H3,B:D,3,0))
That fills rows one by one with the value that it finds. I am hoping that there is a macro that will search the column (I) for the single last non-blank cell and convert the formula answer into a value so I can eventually sum all of the values. I assume it is not a very difficult macro, but I have no experience working with VBA so any help would be appreciated!

[Here is a pic of part of the table I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaFnL.png). Where the 13.8 is I would like for that to be converted to just a value since it is the last non-blank cell in the column. Please let me know if this makes sense or if more info is needed. Thank you!

Comment: I don't follow why you need to convert this to a value. Can you explain further?

Comment: I am using a macro that uses a google maps API to fetch distances and travel times between a base and several locations. Once it finds the travel time I use a VLOOKUP function to relate the addresses to their travel times. I was able to figure it out using a separate reference cell that simply equals the cell that shows the travel time, and then used:    Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("G18").Value     to copy and paste the value, eliminating the need for my original VLOOKUP function that I posted in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nofriendsnojo, if overwriting the formula in a cell (in this case VLOOKUP) is all you need, then please see my code below:

```
Sub paste_values()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cel As Range

'get last non-blank cell in column I
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

'loop that overwrites cell contents with simple values
For Each cel In Range("I1:I" & lastRow)
    cel.Copy
    cel.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next cel

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This is the basic code, it copies values of the cell and then pastes them to the same cell as values. This ultimately gets rid of any formula and converts the result of the formula into a simple value. It is quite common practice.

Of course, you can then add some references like `ThisWorkbook.` or `ActiveSheet.` or whatever scope you need.

I hope this solves your issue or atleast directs you in the right way.